# Intellij change background color of VCS commit changes window

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, background

I'm not sure how or when this happened.  But its annoying and I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

I use subversion and when I open the VCS commit window, the area for the commit message has a white background.  Nice, but I use white text with a very dark background (settings->color->general->default text).  For reasons unknown, this message area picks up all properties of the 'default text' *except* the background color.  Thus I am unable to see anything I write as it is white on white.  I have to highlight the text (that foreground/background does work) to see my mistakes.

Anyone have any idea what controls that background color and where to find it?

Comment: Which version of Idea? In 12 and 13 you should use the Darcula theme.

Comment: In fact, I think it is 14 EAP which just updated a few minutes ago with a patch (no change to this issue).  I use the Dark Pastel theme but again, this is something that only recently popped up.  Either I've changed something which had follow on effects or something in in IntelliJ changed in the past month.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue, started with one of the latest EAPs leading up to 8.0.2, and the issue still exists there.

Comment: I was using 10-13 and wasn't experiencing this. I just installed 14 (Community Edition) and imported my settings from 13 (using RagnorakBlue theme) and all of a sudden I'm having a similar problem - light gray text on a white background i.e. barely readable.

Comment: You may want to add your specific case to this thread at IDEA [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131109)